# Verificar si Activity ha recibido información extra desde un Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

Tengo muchas `Activity` en mi aplicación las cuales pueden ser abiertas desde varios lugares.

Siempre son invocadas desde `Intents`, sólo que a veces me interesa pasarles información extra, y otras veces no.

¿Hay alguna manera de saber cuándo el `Intent` que llama a una `Activity` le ha pasado información extra y cuándo no?

Muestro algunos fragmentos del código.

### Intent que no pasa extras

```
    final Button btnOficio = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_oficio);
    btnOficio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            utilClass.setFabric("btnOficio", TAG, strFechaHoy);
            Intent i = new Intent(BreviarioActivity.this, OficioActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    final Button btnLaudes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_laudes);
    btnLaudes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            utilClass.setFabric("btnLaudes", TAG, strFechaHoy);
            Intent i = new Intent(BreviarioActivity.this, LaudesActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

    //...etc
```

### Intent que sí pasa extras

```
  public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Intent i=null;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_oficio:
                utilClass.setFabric("ctxOficio", TAG, strFecha);
                i = new Intent(this, OficioActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("FECHA", strFecha);
                startActivity(i);
                return true;

            case R.id.nav_laudes:
                utilClass.setFabric("ctxLaudes", TAG, strFecha);
                i = new Intent(this, LaudesActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("FECHA", strFecha);
                startActivity(i);
                return true;

           //más case...

            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Comprobando retorno de `getStringExtra()`

Para saber si has facilitado un extra debes hacer uso de [`Intent.getStringExtra()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras%28%29) y comprobar si el resultado es `null`:

> Returns `String`: the value of an item that previously added with `putExtra()` **or `null` if no `String` value was found**.

En castellano:

> Devuelve `String`: el valor de un elemento que ha sido agregado previamente con `putExtra()` **o `null` si no se encontró el valor `String`**.

Ejemplo:

```
/* final Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent(); */
String strFecha = intent.getStringExtra("FECHA");
if (strFecha == null) {
    /* Hacer lo necesario en caso de NO recibir la fecha */
} else {
    /* Hacer lo necesario en caso de haber recibido la fecha */
}
```

### Comprobando existencia del valor con `hasExtra()`

También podrías hacer uso de [`Intent.hasExtra()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#hasExtra%28java.lang.String%29):

```
/* final Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent(); */
if (intent.hasExtra("FECHA")) {
    /* Hacer lo necesario en caso de NO recibir la fecha */
} else {
    /* Hacer lo necesario en caso de haber recibido la fecha */
}
```

### Comprobando si hay datos extras con `getExtras()`

Una llamada a [`Intent.getExtras()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras%28%29) obtiene una instancia de `Bundle` con los valores o bien `null` en caso de no haber ninguno:

> Returns `Bundle`: the map of all extras previously added with `putExtra()` **or `null` if none have been added**.

En castellano:

> Devuelve `Bundle`: un mapa con todos los extras agregados previamente `putExtra()` **o `null` si no fue agregado ninguno**.

Ejemplo:

```
/* final Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent(); */
if (intent.getExtras() == null) {
    /* Hacer lo necesario en caso de no recibir NINGÚN extra */
} else {
    /* Hacer lo necesario en caso de no recibir algún extra */
}
```

### Proyecto de ejemplo de uso

Proyecto de ejemplo [`EjemploIntent`](https://github.com/ojgarciab/EjemploIntent/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/linaresdigital/android/stackoverflow/ejemplointent/IntentActivity.java) que he creado en github:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_intent);
    tvName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_name);
    String strDate = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_NAME_STRING);
    if (strDate == null) {
        tvName.setText(getText(R.string.cancelled));
    } else {
        tvName.setText(strDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oscar fui directamente a buscar el valor que me interesaba, en este caso usando `getIntent().getStringExtra()`, quedando el código así: **`strFechaHoy = (this.getIntent().getExtras() != null) ? getIntent().getStringExtra("FECHA") : utilClass.getHoy();`** Funciona perfectamente, muchas gracias.

Comment: Esa también es una solución, pero si "FECHA" no existe `strFechaHoy` valdrá `null`, pudiendo provocarte una excepción. Si en tu código no hay posibilidad de enviar otro dato extra y no el de "FECHA" entonces no tendrás problemas.

Comment: No Oscar, si fecha no es pasada en el `Intent`, entonces `strFecha` tomará el valor de la fecha de hoy, que obtengo de un método de la clase `Utils`. Lo he probado llamando la `Activity` desde un `Intent` que no envía extras y me funciona perfectamente.

Comment: He corregido un error de copiar/pegar (un corchete adicional en los ejemplos que cerraba el método en el que probaba el código propuesto) y agregado un ejemplo de la solución que has adoptado.

Comment: Me refiero a que si existe la posibilidad de que envíes otro extra (cualquier cosa, por ejemplo un extra con nombre "AUTOR") entonces `getStringExtra` devolverá `null` si no se mandó "FECHA", por eso te dije que si no existía esa probabilidad entonces no tendrías problemas.

Comment: Es correcto, el único valor que se pasará será la fecha, para aquellos casos en los que la `Activity` tenga que buscar información de una fecha distinta a la fecha de hoy. No se pasarán otros valores. Y, dado que lo que interesa es asignar un valor u otro a `strFechaHoy`, he usado un operador ternario que haga la asignación según el dato haya sido pasado en el `Intent` o no. Muchas gracias por la advertencia y por la respuesta.

Comment: Un placer, como siempre :)

Answer (score 0):

Claro, en el codigo del Activity que se abra , puedes meter el:

```
if(getIntent().hasExtra("FECHA"){
//Hacer algo si tiene extras
}
```

Comment: `getIntent()` es un método, no una variable y `hasExtras` no existe, sólo `getExtras` y éste no tiene parámetros y devuelve un `Bundle` con todos los parámetros, debiendo llamar adicionalmente a `getString()` para obtener un valor de tipo `String` o `null` si éste no existe. Quizá quisiste decir `hasExtra()`.

Comment: Corregido jeje.