# Como iniciar un metodo despues de salir de otra clase

Tags: android, android-studio, clase, método, ejecutar

```
public class RegistrarIngreso{
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   //
   //
   //}
   public void onClick(View view) {
       switch (view.getId()) {
          case R.id.btn1:
             ejecutar_scanner();
             break;
       }
   }
   public void ejecutar_scanner() {

     Intent i = new Intent(RegistrarIngreso.this,Skanner.class);
     startActivity(i);
   }
}
```

La otra clase

```
public class Skanner{
//
//
//
//
   RegistrarIngreso.codeParte.setText(result.getText());

   onBackPressed();
}
```

Ahora que tengo la variable ya en la clase RegistrarIngreso ,lo
que quiero que haga es en secuencia es que ejecute el metodo consultarParte que esta en la clase RegistrarIngreso.

```
public void consultarParte() {
//
//
//
}
```

haber si me dan ideas para mantener el hilo de la ejecucion .

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara. Si lo que quieres es pasar el dato de una clase a otra, lo puedes hacer usando el mismo `Intent` que inicia la otra clase, la cual supongo es una `Activity`. En la respuesta a [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/131890/29967) se explica una forma de hacerlo.

Comment: Hola, el problema es que no son activitys o pantallas por decirlo asi, lo que tu estas usando son clases, entonces desde una clase no podras hacer ello. Te recomendaria crear un nuevo proyecto con un Empty Activity y revises un video de youtube :D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suponiendo que tanto `RegistrarIngreso` como `Skanner` son `Activities`, una vez que `RegistrarIngreso` inicia a `Skanner`, ya no puedes hacer referencia a la actividad anterior.

Por esto mismo, lo que intentas hacer referenciando a `codePart` de forma estática desde `Skanner`, no va a funcionar.

Si una vez que termina `Skanner`, debe retormar `RegistrarIngreso`, entonces en lugar de iniciar `Skanner` con `startActivity(i);` tienes que iniciar `Skanner` con `startActivityForResult(i)`.

Y hacer el `@Override` del método `onActivityResult()` en `RegistrarIngreso` para recibir el resultado y retomar `RegistrarIngreso` cuando `Skanner` retorne.

Para pasarle los datos desde `Skanner` a `RegistrarIngreso` hay varias opciones pero estas dos serían las más factibles para tu escenario:

1) Devolver un resultado como `EXTRA` en el `Intent` que devuelve `Skanner`
2) Guardar los datos en SharedPreferences (y leerlos en `RegistrarIngreso` `onActivityResult()`)

Comment: Gracias por el aporte fue de mucha ayuda.