# Error::'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

Tengo un *MainActiviy* de la siguiente manera:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {                                                                               

Context contexto;                                                                                                               
String totales;                                                                                                                 
ListView list;                                                                                                                  
EditText dateText;                                                                                                              
TextView texto;                                                                                                                 
ImageView image1;                                                                                                               
List<List<List<List<Object>>>> titles  = new 
ArrayList<List<List<List<Object>>>>();                                             
List<List<List<List<Object>>>> titlesCopia  = new 
ArrayList<List<List<List<Object>>>>();                                        
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;                                                                                                      
ArrayAdapter adaptador;                                                                                                         
String usuario = new String("telecom");                                                                                         
String clave = new String("il0v3t3l3c0m@n");                                                                                    
String error = new String("Algo ha fallado");                                                                                   

Integer tamañoArray =0;                                                                                                         
Integer tamañoArray2;                                                                                                           
Integer Numero = 0;                                                                                                             
Integer contador=0;                                                                                                             
List<String> Avisos = new ArrayList<String>();                                                                                  

String date_n = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", 
Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());                            


String credenciales =  usuario + ":" + clave ;;                                                                                 
String credencialesEnBase64 = "Basic " + 
 Base64.encodeToString(credenciales.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);                        

@Override                                                                                                                       
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {                                                                            
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                                                                                         
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);                                                                                     

    contexto = this;                                                                                                            
    adaptador = new ArrayAdapter(this, 
     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Avisos);                                            
    list = findViewById(R.id.list);                                                                                             
    list.setAdapter(adaptador);                                                                                                 
    getPosts();                                                                                                                 
    getSizeArray();                                                                                                             
    PedirAlarmas();                                                                                                             

}                                                                                                                               

private int getSizeArray(){                                                                                                     
    return titles.size();                                                                                                       
}                                                                                                                               

private void PedirAlarmas(){                                                                                                    
    final Handler handler= new Handler();                                                                                       
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {                                                                                        
        @Override                                                                                                               
        public void run() {                                                                                                     
            contador=contador+1;                                                                                                
            getPosts();//llamamos nuestro metodo                                                                                
            handler.postDelayed(this,60000);//se ejecutara cada 10 segundos                                                     
        }                                                                                                                       
    },10000);//empezara a ejecutarse después de 5 milisegundos                                                                  
}                                                                                                                               


private void getPosts() {                                                                                                       
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()                                                                                  
            //.baseUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com")                                                                  
            .baseUrl("http://192.168.0.249:9096/datasnap/rest/TMetodosREST/")                                                   
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())                                                                 
            .build();                                                                                                           
    PostService postService = retrofit.create(PostService.class);                                                               
    Call<Post> call = postService.getPost(credencialesEnBase64);                                                                

            call.enqueue(new Callback<Post>() {                                                                                 
                @Override                                                                                                       
                public void onResponse(Call<Post> call, Response<Post> response) {                                              
                    Post post = (Post) response.body();                                                                         

                    titles.add(post.getResult());                                                                               
                    tamañoArray = titles.size();                                                                                
                    titlesCopia = titles;                                                                                       
                    String title1 = titlesCopia.get(0).get(0).get(0).get(0).toString();                                         
                    double title2 = Double.parseDouble(title1);                                                                 
                    int titles3 = (int) title2;                                                                                 
                    title1 = String.valueOf(titles3);                                                                           

                    if (contador ==0) {                                                                                         

                        for (int i = 0; i < titlesCopia.get(0).get(0).size(); i++) {                                            
                            int l = i;                                                                                          

                            String codigo = titlesCopia.get(0).get(0).get(i).get(0).toString();                                 
                            String cadena1 = titlesCopia.get(0).get(0).get(i).get(1).toString();                                
                            String codigo2 = titlesCopia.get(0).get(0).get(i).get(2).toString();                                
                            String cadena2 = titlesCopia.get(0).get(0).get(i).get(3).toString();                                
                            String codigo3 = titlesCopia.get(0).get(0).get(i).get(4).toString();                                
                            String codigo4 = titlesCopia.get(0).get(0).get(i).get(5).toString();                                

                            totales = codigo + cadena1 + codigo2 + cadena2 + codigo3 + codigo4;                                 
                            Avisos.add(totales);                                                                                
                            contador = contador + 1;                                                                            

                            if (contador==1) {                                                                                  


               Intent intent = new 
        Intent(MainActivity.this,ConfirmacionAlarma.class);  
        intent.putExtra("notificar",totales);                                                                                    

                          new ConfirmacionAlarma(contexto);                                                                     
                            }                                                                                                   
                        }                                                                                                       
                    }                                                                                                           

                    adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();                                                                           
                }                                                                                                               

                @Override                                                                                                       
                public void onFailure(Call<Post> call, Throwable t) {                                                           
                    Log.d("MainActivity", t.getMessage());                                                                      
                }                                                                                                               
            });            }
```

Mi problema es al final cuando llamo a un *alertDialog* y quiero pasarle a este el valor de una variable con un *intent*.
Al abrir el *alertDialog* y llegar al Bundle me da error como que lo viene del *Intent* esta vacio y ya no se que hacer,no se si es problema de como esta hecho el *alertDialog* el cual expongo aqui:

```
public class ConfirmacionAlarma  extends AppCompatActivity {



public ConfirmacionAlarma(Context contexto)
{


    final Dialog dialogo = new Dialog(contexto);


    dialogo.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialogo.setCancelable(false);
    dialogo.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialogo.setContentView(R.layout.dialogo_alarma);



    final TextView notiAlarm = (TextView) dialogo.findViewById(R.id.notificacionAlarma);

    TextView descAlarm = (TextView) dialogo.findViewById(R.id.DescAlarma);
    TextView contAla = (TextView) dialogo.findViewById(R.id.ContadorAlarmas);
    EditText fechaAlar = (EditText) dialogo.findViewById(R.id.Fecha);
    ImageView camapana = (ImageView) dialogo.findViewById(R.id.image1);
    Button ConfirmarAviso = (Button) dialogo.findViewById(R.id.Aceptar);

    Bundle nuevoTotales = getIntent().getExtras();
    String nom = nuevoTotales.getString("notificar");
    descAlarm.setText(nom);


    ConfirmarAviso.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dialogo.dismiss();
        }
    });




    dialogo.show();


}
```

}

Probé de todo,pero insisto,no se si es problema de como lo tengo montado,realmente es un *mainActivity* y luego un alertDialog que llamo desde fuera.

Añado el error que me da :

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.lista, PID: 19216
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
>           at com.example.lista.Interface.ConfirmacionAlarma.(ConfirmacionAlarma.java:49)
>           at com.example.lista.Interface.MainActivity$2.onResponse(MainActivity.java:154)
>           at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

Comment: El intent sólo es pasado cuando `contador=1`, en otros casos no es pasado. Por tanto para recibir el intent tienes que verificar primero si no es nulo. Puede que esté fallando porque la condición que crea el intent no se cumplió y por tanto es nulo. Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/131910/29967) y los comentarios que hay en ella.

Comment: @willy22 El bundle con los datos que recibes es null ya que debe ser recibido dentro del método onCreate() de la Activity "destino", revisa mi respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba accediento directamente al valor del Extra. Debería funcionar y no darte problemas si sigue fallando adjunta también el stack completo del error.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String nom = intent.getStringExtra("notificar");
```

Edito la respuesta ya he visto donde esta el error, estas ejecutando este código:

```
Intent intent = new 
Intent(MainActivity.this,ConfirmacionAlarma.class);  
intent.putExtra("notificar",totales);                                                                                    

new ConfirmacionAlarma(contexto);
```

Cuando en realidad lo que deberías estar ejecutando seria un:

```
Intent intent = new 
Intent(MainActivity.this,ConfirmacionAlarma.class);  
intent.putExtra("notificar",totales);

startActivity(intent);
```

Cambiando esto por el new ConfirmacionAlarma(contexto) abrirás una nueva actividad y podrás acceder a los Extras.

Comment: Me sigue fallando,dice que todo Null y no lo entiendo,subo el error completo

Answer (score 0):

El problema se debe a que el bundle que estas tratando de leer tiene un  valor null esto es debido a que estas tratando de obtener el bundle en este método, lo cual es incorrecto:

```
public ConfirmacionAlarma(Context contexto)
{
    ...
    ...
    Bundle nuevoTotales = getIntent().getExtras();
    String nom = nuevoTotales.getString("notificar")
    ...
    ...
}
```

**Para que recibas correctamente los datos en la Activity debes obtenerlos dentro del método `onCreate()`.**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ....
    ....
    Bundle nuevoTotales = getIntent().getExtras();
    String nom = nuevoTotales.getString("notificar")

   ....
   ....
}
```

---

> El problema que tengo es que no se donde poner el OnCreate dentro del
>   alertDialog en la clase ConfirmacionAlarma ya que cuando en el
>   ActivityMain llamo al metodo new ConfirmacionAlarma(contexto) ya no
>   pasa por el OnCreate de la clase ConfirmacionAlarma.

En este caso tienes que obtener los valores en `onCreate()` de la `Activity` como he mencionado anteriormente y al llamar la clase  `new ConfirmacionAlarma(.....)`  en realidad tendrías que modificar el constructor de esta clase para que reciba los valores que necesitas

Ejemplo:

```
public ConfirmacionAlarma(Context contexto, String nombre)
{
    ...
    ...
    String nom = nombre;
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: El problema que tengo es que no se donde poner el OnCreate dentro del alertDialog en la clase ConfirmacionAlarma ya que cuando en el ActivityMain llamo al metodo  new ConfirmacionAlarma(contexto) ya no pasa por el OnCreate de la clase ConfirmacionAlarma. ¿Donde pongo lo del OnCreate? en la Activity main?Un saludo!

Comment: En este caso tienes que obtener los valores en onCreate() y modificar el constructor de la clase ConfitmacionAlarma, revisa mi actualización.

Comment: Nada,sigue sin irme al parecer creo el bundle en el onCreate pero claro el intent salta en el onResponse y cuando pasa por el Bundle del onCreate claro recibe un nulo porque aun no hizo el intent.Entonces dije,voy a ponerlo todo junto hice el intent e inmediatamente despues el Bundle y me sigue diciendo que null el Bundle,el intent si lo hace porque la cadena tiene valor pero al hacer el Bundlle nada,me dice que Null.Hice tanto lo que tu me dijiste como las pruebas que te digo.No entiendo que pasa.