# Como llamar una variable de un activity a otro?

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy resolviendo un ejercicio en donde se necesita ingresar el Nombre de un trabajador y las horas trabajadas, dependiendo de las horas hay que calcular horas extra y el sueldo.
El la aplicacion los ingresos de datos tienen que darse en un activity y los resultados en otro activity.

En este activity tengo el ingreso de datos que se guardan en un `ArrayList` y cuando ya se hayan ingresado los datos se cambia al otro activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText edtNom,edtHoras;
    private Button btnGuardar,btnMostrar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnGuardar=findViewById(R.id.btn_guardar);
        btnMostrar=findViewById(R.id.btn_mostrar);
        edtHoras=findViewById(R.id.edt_hor);
        edtNom=findViewById(R.id.edt_nom);
        ArrayList<Trabajador> lista_trabajador=new ArrayList<>();
        btnGuardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String nombre;
                int horas;
                nombre=edtNom.getText().toString();
                try
                {
                    horas=Integer.parseInt(edtHoras.getText().toString());
                    Trabajador t=new Trabajador(nombre,horas);
                    lista_trabajador.add(t);
                    edtNom.setText("");
                    edtHoras.setText("");
                    edtNom.requestFocus();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Persona guardada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException ex)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Debe ingresar las horas trabajadas.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        btnMostrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent z=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MostrarDatos_activity.class);
                z.putExtra("lista",lista_trabajador);
                startActivity(z);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

En este activity estoy definiendo los datos ingresados en el `TextView`, aca surge mi problema, quiero llamar a la variable `edtHoras` del primer activity para mandarsela como parametro al metodo y asi hacer en calculo del sueldo con las horas extra (no se si se me entiende la idea, soy nuevo programando) Mi idea era definirlo en una nueva variable y convertirlo a String para poder imprimirlo en el `TextView`
`int n1=Integer.parseInt(edtHoras.getText().toString());` pero no me toma el `edtHoras` por estar en otro activity

```
public class MostrarDatos_activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView tvMostrar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mostrar_datos);
        tvMostrar=findViewById(R.id.tv_mostrar);
        ArrayList<Trabajador> lstTrabajador=(ArrayList<Trabajador>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("lista");
        String ax="";
        Metodos z=new Metodos();
        for (Trabajador x:lstTrabajador){
            ax=ax + "nombre: " + x.getNombre() +"  "+"horas: " + x.getHoras() + "\n";
        }
        tvMostrar.setText(ax);

    }
}
```

CLASES

```
package com.example.ejercicio3;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Trabajador implements Serializable
{
    private String nombre;
    private int horas;

    public Trabajador(){

    }
    public Trabajador(String nombre, int horas){
        this.nombre=nombre;
        this.horas=horas;

    }

    public String getNombre() {return nombre;}

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {this.nombre = nombre;}

    public int getHoras() {return horas;}

    public void setHoras(int horas) {this.horas = horas;}

}
```

```
package com.example.ejercicio3;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Metodos implements Serializable {
    public int HorasExtra(int a){
        int horas = 0;
        int horasE = 0;
        if (a > 40) {
            horas = a-40;
            horasE = horas * 6500;
            a = (40 * 5500);
            return (a+horasE);
        }
        else {
            a=a*4000;
            return a;
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Verificar si Activity ha recibido información extra desde un Intent](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/131890/verificar-si-activity-ha-recibido-informaci%c3%b3n-extra-desde-un-intent). Para pasar datos entre diferentes `Activity` debes usar `Intent`. Aunque Android recomienda actualmente Componente de Navegación, DataBinding, etc. De hecho, las Apps modernas, si implementas todas las recomendaciones de Android, pueden hacerse con una sola Activity, y varios Fragment. El paso de información y más cosas se hacen de un modo más simple y más seguro.

Comment: Mmm me aclara un poco pero no me soluciona el problema, no tengo conocimientos para entender mucho esas respuestas, en mi codigo se estan enviando las horas metidas en la lista con el ```Intent``` y el ```putExtra```, ahora estando en el segundo activity, como se podria extraer las horas de la lista y luego enviarselas como parametro a ```Metodos```?

Comment: En el apartado titulado **Proyecto de ejemplo de uso** te muestra cómo obtener el intent en el otro Activity y a partir de ahí lo puedes mandar a donde quieras.

Comment: Por otra parte, ¿hiciste debug de lo que hay en `lstTrabajador`? ¿Está el dato del `nombre` pero las horas no?

Comment: Ahora me doy cuenta que mi problema es otro, yo ya envie los datos entre activities, obtuve el intent del primer activity con ```ArrayList<Trabajador> lstTrabajador=``` ```(ArrayList<Trabajador>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("lista");``` pero los datos estan dentro de una lista y lo que quiero mandar a los metodos son solamente las horas, como puedo sacar las horas de la lista y mandarsela a los metodos?

Comment: El dato de las horas si esta en la lista, al hacer el ```setText``` en el ```tvMostrar``` si aparecen las horas con los respectivos nombres, con respecto al debug no tengo conocimientos ya que no es materia que hemos pasado con mi profesor, supongo que en un futuro si.

Comment: Puedes usar el método del objeto si lo tuviera. Imagina que `Trabajador` tiene un método `getHora()`, pues si invocas ese método, obtendrás la hora. O, en vez de pasar el objeto en el Intent, pasas la hora directamente.

Comment: De hecho, ya veo que eso haces, aquí: `ax=ax + "nombre: " + x.getNombre() +"  "+"horas: " + x.getHoras() + "\n";` entonces, no entiendo cuál es el problema exactamente ¿? En cuanto a *mandárselos a los métodos* no sé a qué te refieres.

Comment: Tengo una clase llamada ```Metodos``` en donde se hacen los calculos de las horas extra para sacar el sueldo y eso agregarlo al ```ax```, lo que no se hacer es la linea de codigo para mandarle solo la ahora a la clase ```Metodos``` para que haga los calculos.

Comment: Edite mis clases en la pregunta por si quieres echarle un vistazo

Comment: Pues tendrías que crear una instancia de esa clase y pasarle le hora. Algo así: `Metodos metodos = new Metodos();` y luego: `int horasExtra = metodos.HorasExtra(horas);` y luego usar `horasExtra` que será el valor de las horas extras calculadas.

Comment: Y, si quieres hacerlo dentro del `for`, puedes hacer algo así: **`for (Trabajador x:lstTrabajador){
            ax=ax + "nombre: " + x.getNombre() +"  horas: " + x.getHoras() +"  horas extra: " + z.HorasExtra(x.getHoras())+ "\n";
        }`** Es decir, aquí: `z.HorasExtra(x.getHoras())` mandas a calcula las horas extra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No parece que haya problemas con la forma de enviar / recuperar el `Intent`, aunque deberías verificar los posibles nulos antes de pasar a usar los valores. Pero no me detendré en eso, porque parece ser un ejercicio... <sup>1</sup>.

Si lo que quieres es calcular también las horas extra, sólo tienes que llamar al método que te calcula ese valor, pasándole el valor de las horas. Algo así:

```
    Metodos z=new Metodos();
    for (Trabajador x:lstTrabajador){
        ax=ax + "nombre: " + x.getNombre() +"  horas: " + x.getHoras() +"  horas extra: " + z.HorasExtra(x.getHoras()) + "\n";
    }
    tvMostrar.setText(ax);
```

### PD

Considera aplicar la [*convención de nombre* recomendada por Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/78423/29967). El método `HorasExtra` debería empezar por un verbo: `get`, `calculate`, `calcular`, `obtener` y escribirse en *camelCase*. En lugar de `HorasExtra` podría llamarse `getHorasExtra()` porque no sólo las calcula, sino que las devuelve.

---

#### Notas

1. Ver al respecto: [Verificar si Activity ha recibido información extra desde un Intent](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/131890/29967)

Comment: Al final me enrede solo y el problema era muy simple, muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: @LiamJonesAstorga eso vi. No obstante, no pierdas de vista lo dicho en la respuesta a la otra pregunta. No siempre habrá extras en un `Intent`, por tanto eso debe verificarse o tu código podría fallar en esos casos con un NPE.

Comment: Lo tendre en cuenta!